# Using Arithmetic operators in parameters of a Function

Tags: javascript, function, math, operators

I tried to do it but didn't work
I want to achieve something like this:

```
function clubMember(clubName, women + men, women, men) {
  const club = `${clubName} club has ${women + men} members including ${women} Women and ${men} Men`
  return club
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: [Just remove `women + men` from the parameter list?](https://jsbin.com/yitoyek/edit?js,console)

Comment: Why do you want to do the addition in the parameter list?

Comment: I just wanted to know is it possible?
Thanks @PresidentJamesK.Polk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: no, you can't put arithmetic operators as a parameter.

As far as I know, there are no languages that gives you ability to calculate as a parameter.

However, you could do something like this if you wish:

```
function clubMember(clubName, total, women, men) {
  const club = `${clubName} club has ${total} members including ${women} Women and ${men} Men`;
  return club;
}
clubMember(club, women+men, women, men);
```